# Passing Nullable Int using reflection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, reflection

i am using this code

```
//Rextester.Program.Main is the entry point for your code. Don't change it.
//Compiler version 4.0.30319.17929 for Microsoft (R) .NET Framework 4.5

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Reflection;

namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new Program().DoTest();
        }

        public void DoTest()
        {
            var a = LoggingAdvice<asd>.Create(new a());
            a.targetMethod("nadeem", 123, null);
        }


    }

    public class LoggingAdvice<T> : DispatchProxy
    {
        private T _decorated;

        protected override object Invoke(MethodInfo targetMethod, object[] args)
        {
            var result = targetMethod.Invoke(_decorated, args);
            var resultTask = result as Task;

            return result;
        }


        public static T Create(T decorated)
        {
            object proxy = Create<T, LoggingAdvice<T>>();
            ((LoggingAdvice<T>)proxy).SetParameters(decorated);
            return (T)proxy;
        }

        private void SetParameters(T decorated)
        {
            if (decorated == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(decorated));
            }

            _decorated = decorated;
        }

    }
    public class asd
    {
        public asd()
        {

        }
        public int targetMethod(string name, int number, int? count)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(name);
            Console.WriteLine(number);
            Console.WriteLine(count.HasValue ? count.Value.ToString() : "NULL");
            return 1;
        }          
    }
}
```

the most important thing about it, is this line of code

```
var result = targetMethod.Invoke(_decorated, args);
```

the target method has 3 parameters, one of them is nullable integer as the following

```
public int targetMethod(string name, int number, int? count)
```

the args that is getting passed to Invoke method has the following values as you can view it in the visual studio debugging mode:

["nadeem", 123, (null)]

the invoke is raising an exception that i cannot convert string to nullable integer.

how i can avoid this type of issue, note that i am not sure which function i am going to be invoked, i would only know it on runtime.

Comment: i think i have missed to explain something, and tha tis why i have shared the url, 
I am using DispatchProxy, and i am invoking the method with DispatchProxy.Invoke, and it gets the parameters from there as object[]

Comment: i have added a sample code, but using your tool DispatchProxy couldnot be found part of system.reflection

Comment: What version of .NET Framework / .NET Core are you using? The code works for me in .NET Core 2.1 (well, with a few fixes, fixing compiler error by replacing 'new a()' with 'new asd()', and extracting interface from 'asd' to use as generic type argument in 'Create<...>').

Comment: It also works with .NET Framework 4.6 plus System.Reflection.DispatchProxy 4.5.1. In both NETCore 2.1 and NetFX 4.6, DispatchProxy insists (by throwing an exception) that the type being proxied ('asd') must be an interface. Once I extract an interface, it works. It can be that your issue only reproduces in a specific versions of .NET and System.Reflection.DispatchProxy package -- please list the exact versions